# Zend_Cache: Which cache backend to use in a cluster?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, caching

We are currently using file based cache in a web-server cluster causing Magento having different caches on each webserver. So the automatic cache clearing - for example if you chance a configuration setting in the backend - is not working.

Which cache system do you recommend:

- It should support tagging
- Short work in the network

The PHP module for memcached seems to be buggy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Redis with the new Zend Cache Adapter by Colin Mollenhour.
The adapter supports tagging and can be accessed over TCP/IP.

You can find the project here:

https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis

The project comes with a magento installation tutorial.